# azure synapse spark sql pool unable to create database

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I have created my spark pool in azure synapse, but when i try creating my database using the below code  its giving me error- any help in what am doing wrong:

```
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE  nyctaxi_ksa7")
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("nyctaxi.trip")

AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_6859/2561526676.py in <module>
----> 1 spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE  nyctaxi_ksa7")
      2 df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("nyctaxi.trip")

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    721         [Row(f1=1, f2='row1'), Row(f1=2, f2='row2'), Row(f1=3, f2='row3')]
    722         """
--> 723         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    724 
    725     def table(self, tableName):

~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    116                 # JVM exception message.
--> 117                 raise converted from None
    118             else:
    119                 raise

AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is sometimes seen if there is an issue with the workspace. You can try creating a new workspace. If the error persists, you can raise a support ticket for the support engineers to investigate more on the issue.

I have repro’d and created the database in the synapse spark pool without errors.

```
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE sampledb1")

df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("sampledb1.tb1")
```

[image]

Comment: EXACT problem I had, I think it had to do with too much going on in the storage account and someone deleted the container that synapse was using...